# Whats wrong in my xsd schema ? It gives type element is not declared on include of another xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to validate a xml using schema but the problem is xsd is not valid, i tried ti tested if it valid or not, it gives error XSD schema Error: Type 'testNamespaces:eltyp_string035' is not declared.
My code to verify the schema is here :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace testingXmlValidation
{
    class Program
    {
        static StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                string xsdPath = null;
                 xsdPath = "C:/Users/testing/a.xsd";
                elementName = "SpeTrans";

                try
                {
                    XmlSchemaCollection sc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
                    sc.Add("testNamespaces", xsdPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("No Schema error.");
                }
                catch (XmlSchemaException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("XSD schema Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                }

                Console.ReadKey();       

         }  
    }

}
```

My main xsd file is below **It seems that either the problem is in this include  or the file command.xsd which is included because it contains "eltyp_string035" declaration** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Designer Edition 13.2.0.5980 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<!-- Version 1.0.1  du 14/09/2015: TypNoiSuiviE à TypNotSuiviE -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="testNamespaces">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/KT-iNDIA/September/24thseptember2015-KtIndia/Shakhar24092015/xsdFile/common.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="trans">                
                <xs:element name="ContDest" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0" xmlns="testNamespaces">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Nom du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MailDest" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0" xmlns="testNamespaces">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Email du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TelDest" type="eltyp_string020" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Téléphone du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>                   
                <xs:element name="ValDecAssu" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Valeur Assurance En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDevAssu" minOccurs="0" default="EUR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Devise valeur Assurance</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

and common.xsd is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Designer Edition 13.1.0.5909 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<!--Version 1.0.1 du 24/06/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.2 du 07/07/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.3 du 16/07/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.4 du 21/07/2015  - Correction liste des trans/modtrans/Col -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--Element De base -->

    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="eltyp_string032">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="32" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="eltyp_string035">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="35" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
<!--Fin des ꭩments de type complexes-->
```

Why the main.xsd is not able to get the declaration of "eltyp_string035"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main XSD add the **xmlns="testNamespaces"** to your xs:schema element.

When you write type="eltyp_string035", the XSD processor considers "eltyp_string035" as a qualified name, i.e. with a namespace. Since your schema doesn't define a default namespace, "eltyp_string035" = {}eltyp_string035.

You are including a schema that has no targetNamespace in a schema that has one. This is sometimes referred to as a *chameleonic* include, which means all the components in the included schema assume the namespace of the including schema (here testNamespaces). Therefore, it looks for {testNamespaces}eltyp_string035.

These are your corrected schemas; compare them to what you have, and read a bit on XML namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Designer Edition 13.2.0.5980 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<!-- Version 1.0.1  du 14/09/2015: TypNoiSuiviE à TypNotSuiviE -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="testNamespaces" xmlns="testNamespaces">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="Spetrans">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="TypNotSuiviE" minOccurs="0" default="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Forçage Type de notification pour le suivi « Expéditeur »</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TypNotSuiviO" minOccurs="0" default="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Forçage Type de notification pour le suivi « Donneur d’ordre »</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TypNotSuiviD" minOccurs="1" default="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Forçage Type de notification pour le suivi « Donneur d’ordre »</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ContDest" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Nom du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MailDest" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Email du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TelDest" type="eltyp_string020" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Téléphone du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="GsmDest" type="eltyp_string020" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Téléphone GSM du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDecAssu" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Valeur Assurance En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDevAssu" minOccurs="0" default="EUR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Devise valeur Assurance</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string003">
                            <xs:enumeration value="EUR" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDecDou" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Valeur Douane En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDevDou" minOccurs="0" default="EUR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Devise valeur Douane</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string003">
                            <xs:enumeration value="EUR" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDecRep" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Valeur déclarée CRBT En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDevRep" minOccurs="0" default="EUR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Devise valeur déclarée CRBT</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string003">
                            <xs:enumeration value="EUR" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TypeRep" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Type de REP (Aller ou Retour) Ou bien  Type du SWAP déclaré (Aller ou Retour)
Valeur par défaut à vide.
SWPA = SWAP Aller, SWPR = SWAP Retour
REPA = REP Aller, REPR = REP Retour
</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string004">
                            <xs:enumeration value="" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="SWPA" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="SWPR" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="REPA" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="REPR" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RepRet" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>N° Chronopost du  REP ou du SWAP retour 
Si le colis déclaré est un SWAP Aller, indiquer ici le N° du Retour. Si le colis déclaré est un REP Aller, indiquer ici le N° du Retour.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string013" />
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RepDep" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>N° Chronopost du  REP ou du SWAP aller
Si le colis déclaré est un SWAP Retour, indiquer ici le N° du Aller. Si le colis déclaré est un REP Retour, indiquer ici le N° du Aller
</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string013" />
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CptPart" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>information fourni par Chronopost</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DatDebRdv" type="Eltyp_DateAAAAMMJJHHMM" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation> Date de début de rendez-vous Sous la forme AAAAMMJJHHMM Uniquement pour les produits à livraison sur RDV</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DatFinRdv" type="Eltyp_DateAAAAMMJJHHMM" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation> Date de fin de rendez-vous Sous la forme AAAAMMJJHHMM Uniquement pour les produits à livraison sur RDV</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="LivExpVen" minOccurs="0" default="A">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Jour de livraison souhaité pour les envois du vendredi
0 : Normal ,1: Lundi, 2: Mardi, 3: Mercredi, 4: Jeudi, 5: Vend et 6: Samedi 
« A » Déterminé par Mutualisation Expédition
</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string001">
                            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="2" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="3" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="4" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="5" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="6" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="A" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="GpsLivLat" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Coordonnées GPS du point à livrer : Latitude </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="GpsLivLon" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Coordonnées GPS du point à livrer : Longitude </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="InstPart1" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Informations libre émetteur</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="InstPart2" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Informations libre émetteur</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="NumCR" type="eltyp_string011" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Informations libre émetteur</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MonTransHT" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Montant du transport HT  En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MonTransTTC" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Montant du transport TTC En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MonTransTVA" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Montant du transport TVA En Centimes</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string009">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ValDevTrans" minOccurs="0" default="EUR">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Devise valeur Assurance</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="eltyp_string003">
                            <xs:enumeration value="EUR" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RefSwap" type="eltyp_string045" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Référence SWAP</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="NumColEmet" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>N° interne du colis chez l'émetteur Ligne à disposition émetteur</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RefExp" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Référence Expéditeur Ligne à disposition émetteur</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Common:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Designer Edition 13.1.0.5909 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<!--Version 1.0.1 du 24/06/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.2 du 07/07/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.3 du 16/07/2015  -->
<!--Version 1.0.4 du 21/07/2015  - Correction liste des trans/modtrans/Col -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <!--Element De base -->

    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string032">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="32" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string035">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="35" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string020">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string009">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="9" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string003">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="3" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string004">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string013">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="13" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string045">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="45" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string001">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="eltyp_string011">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="11" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Eltyp_DateAAAAMMJJHHMM">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
<!--Fin des ꭩments de type complexes-->
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer, but i couldn't understand, what i have to do ? Do i need to remove "xmlns="testNamespaces" from the top of my main.xsd or do i have to remove "xmlns="testNamespaces"" from "  <xs:element name="ContDest" type="eltyp_string035" minOccurs="0" xmlns="testNamespaces">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Nom du contact Destinataire</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>" Could you please explain a bit more ? thanks

Comment: Actually there was no targetNamespace="testNamespaces" before, i had added it following this link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317611 (even then error is still same) now it is : "Type 'testNamespaces:eltyp_string035' is not declared." before not doing targetNamespace="testNamespaces" and xmlns="testnamespaces" at element  it was giving "Type eltyp_string035' is not declared."

Comment: Try my corrected schemas; if you're still getting errors re: types in the common file, then your problem is that the include is not resolved.

Comment: thanks but again , Type 'testNamespaces:eltyp_string035' is not declared.

Comment: Infact there was no namespace="xmlns" and targetNamespace="testNamespaces" ,I  had kept it myself because i had an error  "Type eltyp_string035' is not declared." , so i folowed this link   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317611 , now after adding them i have Type 'testNamespaces:eltyp_string035'  , So xsd file given to me for xml validation had no namespace and targetNamespace

Comment: Infact there was no namespace="xmlns" and targetNamespace="testNamespaces" ,I  had kept it myself because i had an error  "Type eltyp_string035' is not declared." , so i folowed this link   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317611 , now after adding them i have Type 'testNamespaces:eltyp_string035'  , So xsd file given to me for xml validation had no namespace and targetNamespace

Comment: So you have deleted xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" from each element and added at top of common.xsd, Is this the only reason made it work ?

Comment: @xavxav, I would use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935868/validate-xsd-in-c-sharp-as-if-it-were-an-xml-doesnt-give-expected-warnings/14948129#14948129) instead; use an XmlSchemaSet, loaded as shown (to make sure there is a source uri). My schemas would then work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer. In fact there was nothing wrong with the `xsd` code, I kept `targetNamespace="testNamespaces"` and `"xmlns="testNamespaces"` intentionally in the code because I got error of type element not declared, and found some solution here on  this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317611) but it was not my problem.

My problem was I had opened the `xsd` file in *Notepad++* so some invisible data was appended to the texts written in. So when i opened the code written by @Petru and pasted it, it could work. But what i gave to him was only small part of my `xsd` file. But when i integrated his code for my big file it could not work.

Suddenly it came to mind lets open the `.xsd` in Visual Studio and as I opened it there it could work. :)